# Converting php loop to python

Tags: php, python, arrays, mongodb

I need help to convert some php code to python. The code takes the result from mongodb cursor and using loop generates an specific array. I need to produce the same array using python code.

Here is how mongodb result looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => example.com
            [host] => 246.156.18.221
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => example2.com
            [host] => 246.156.18.221
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => example3.com
            [host] => 96.235.15.251
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => example4.com
            [host] => 96.235.15.251
        )
)
```

And here is how it looks like when I run it through the php loop:

```
Array
(
    [246.156.18.221] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
            [value] => example.com
            [host] => 246.156.18.221
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
            [value] => example2.com
            [host] => 246.156.18.221
                )
    )
    [96.235.15.251] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
            [value] => example3.com
            [host] => 96.235.15.251
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
            [value] => example4.com
            [host] => 96.235.15.251
                )
    )
)
```

This is the php code I'm using to produce the second array:

```
$result = array();
foreach($mongo_data as $data){
    $result[$data['host']][] = $data;
}
print_r($result);
```

Now, I need to generate the same array as the second one using python code.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def repack(mongo_data):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for data in mongo_data:
        result[data["host"]].append(data)
    return result
```

then

```
mongo_data = [
    {"value": "example.com",  "host": "246.156.18.221"},
    {"value": "example2.com", "host": "246.156.18.221"},
    {"value": "example3.com", "host": "96.235.15.251"},
    {"value": "example4.com", "host": "96.235.15.251"}
]

new_data = repack(mongo_data)
```

gives

```
{
    '246.156.18.221': [
        {'value': 'example.com', 'host': '246.156.18.221'},
        {'value': 'example2.com', 'host': '246.156.18.221'}
    ],
    '96.235.15.251': [
        {'value': 'example3.com', 'host': '96.235.15.251'},
        {'value': 'example4.com', 'host': '96.235.15.251'}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print {data["host"]:data for data in mongo_data}
```

maybe?

Comment: This does not work; you only get the last value for each host.